# hypergeometric function in terms of Pochammer polynomials

Tags: statistics, hypergeometric-function, pochhammer-symbol

How to find the hypergeometric function

$$  {_2}F_1(1,1-k;k+r+2;-1) $$, with $k, r\in \mathbb{Z_\geq 1},$

in terms of the finite sum of Pochhammer polynomials ?

Comment: The factor $(1 - k)_i$ becomes zero for $i \geq k$.

Comment: Thanks @Maxim, but I need the upper limit of the sum to be a function of r and not k.